# Windows 10 virtual desktop from command line

Tags: cmd, windows-10, shortcut

I would like to have a shortcut file that creates multiple Windows 10 virtual desktops, then for each screen to run its own programs.

I know so far how to run multiple programs from Command line by using

```
@echo off
cd "to software directory"
start "software.exe"

cd "another one"
start "another.exe"

exit
```

(Code from http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/launch-multiple-programs-single-shortcut-using-batch-file/)

Now what I couldn't find online is a way to auto create virtual desktops from command line, I could've used C# and do all that, but again i want a simpler way...
Is it possible?

Comment: I want to know this too... Any update guys ?

Comment: Strictly from `CMD`, I don't think there's a way.  However, as a theoretical guide for further research and experimentation, you might be able to cleverly make use of `psexec` in your batch/cmd file and might find it to be possible to accomplish what you want that way.

Comment: Since I found this question while searching for a way to *start* applications on all virtual desktops, I thought it might help others if I linked to the solution to my question: https://superuser.com/a/1808313/89165

Answer (score 4):

I made this tool that presses the keys: https://github.com/ITCMD/Win-Tab

Syntax: `Win+Tab.exe` 
Its as easy as that. Enjoy!

Comment: A neat trick! +1 for an `exe` that you can run from the shell

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: You save my life. My Windows key is broken and this is perfect. Now I will use AHK to code up a bunch of my most common `Win+`  key combinations :-)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like there is any way to manipulate virtual desktops from CMD by itself.

However, one possible way of creating virtual desktops through a batch script would be to compile https://github.com/MScholtes/VirtualDesktop and place the executable in your path, or calling it directly from your script. This is probably the simplest way of doing what you're asking.

Comment: Note they also made a [repo](https://github.com/MScholtes/PSVirtualDesktop) for a powershell module

Answer (score 0):

It's achievable using Robot class in the JAVA AWT package that generates native system inputs.

```
echo off
echo import java.awt.AWTException; > VirtualDesktop.java
echo import java.awt.Robot; >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo import java.io.IOException; >> VirtualDesktop.java

echo public class VirtualDesktop ^{ >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo public static void main (String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException ^{ >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo Robot robo=new Robot(); >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS); >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D); >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D); >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS); >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo    String[] cmd ^= ^{ >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo            "cmd", >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo            "/c", >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo            "notepad.exe" >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo            }; >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)); >> VirtualDesktop.java
    
echo } >> VirtualDesktop.java
echo } >> VirtualDesktop.java
javac VirtualDesktop.java
java VirtualDesktop
```